# ImageMagick Edge Detection - Picture To Line Drawing

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to transform an image to line drawing, exactly like on this website (default settings):

https://tech-lagoon.com/imagechef/en/image-to-edge.html

I am using Image Magick to try to achieve the exact same results, but currently fail to do so.
I have tried using canny edge filter or -edge 1 but the results are not as expected.
The closest thing I have manage to achieve to the above website is the following command:

`magick input.png -colorspace Gray -morphology EdgeOut Octagon -negate  out.bmp`

Here is my original image:
[image]

Here is the image I am trying to obtain: (just black lines on a white background, and thick black lines, without "double outline" like you see in my obtained image, in the collar of the dog. I just want one line)

[image]

Here is what I get when I run the Image Magick command from above:
[image]

Any suggestions to get the desired result?
It would be even better if I could obtain the same image as the one from tech-lagoon but also remove all lines that are not black (for example the wall different color line, that is very thin)

EDIT 1:
Trying various morphology got me a good result, but I still need some help. I need to "denoise" and remove scattered black dots.

The command that works is
`-colorspace Gray   -morphology EdgeOut  Diamond:3 -negate  -threshold 90%%  -define morphology:compose=Lighten  -morphology Convolve "Blur:0x1>"`

For the image:
[image]

Gets me:
[image]

I would like to "clean" it up a bit, because the lines are not perfect everywhere. Any ideas for denoising a bit and improving the black lines so they are more smooth?

Answer (score 2):

The black lines you want seem to already be in the image. How about turning everything that is not black into white?

```
magick dog.png -fill white -fuzz 20% +opaque black result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it does not apply to all images I have. A command that works very good is: -colorspace Gray   -morphology EdgeOut  Diamond:3 -negate  -threshold 90%%  -define morphology:compose=Lighten  -morphology Convolve "Blur:0x1>"  The problem is that I have some noise left in the images, some "scattered" black dots, that I would like to remove. Any ideas?